# How does 'having an idea of something' differ from 'mental existence'?

Tags: ontology, anselm

<sub>Source: pp 38-39, *Philosophy: A Complete Introduction* (2012) by [Prof Sharon Kaye (MA PhD in Philosophy, U. Toronto)](http://sites.jcu.edu/philosophy/professor/sharon-kaye/)</sub>

> Perhaps the problem lies in Anselm's twofold conception of 
>   existence. Anselm sets out to prove that God has being-in-reality 
>   in addition to being-in-the-mind —  as though being-in-reality 
>   and being-in-the-mind are two different ways for something to 
>   exist. But, on closer examination, this is a strange proposal.
>
> When you say 'Santa Claus exists in my mind', what you 
>   really mean is 'I have an idea of Santa.' **And having an idea 
>   of something doesn't necessarily mean that thing has mental 
>   existence.**
>
> Consider what happens in your brain when you think of Santa — 
>   certain neurons fire. It's not as though a little guy in a red suit 
>   literally pops into your head. It may *feel* like that, especially if 
>   you have a vivid imagination — it feels as though you can 'see' 
>   Santa in your mind. But a thought is actually an action — it's a 
>   tiny motion in your brain; it's not a *thing* at all.
>
> If there is no such thing as 'being-in-the-mind', then Anselm's 
>   proof cannot get off the ground.

Even the 3rd paragraph's example with Santa does not aid me to comprehend the distinction asserted by the bold between **having an idea 
of something** vs **mental existence**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have read Kaye's text that you've just quoted several times quite carefully, and I can't see the force of her objection. She is assuming that for Anselm for us to think about God is for God himself to be existing in our heads. In other words she's saying Anselm has gone wrong by assuming a principle like the following:

(1) If I am thinking of x having some feature F, then there is an object in my mind (called O) which is F.

Kaye points out, correctly, that (1) is clearly false. When I think of a rock, my mental representation of that rock is not itself a mineral. 
Kaye seems to be saying that since (1) is clearly false, and Anselm's argument turns on (1), therefore, Anselm's argument doesn't get off the ground.

But I don't see why Anselm is committed to (1) at all. Anselm could deny (1) and just as easily say:

(1*) If I am thinking of x having some feature F, then I have some mental representation r that represents x's having F.

and then the argument could continue something like:

- (2) If I have a mental representation r that represents x's having F,
  then either r corresponds to a real object (i.e. not a mental
  representation) that has F or r does not correspond to a real object.
  (Premise)
- (3) I am thinking of God as being the greatest conceivable being,
  therefore I have an r that represents God as being the greatest
  conceivable being. (by universal instantiation of 1*)
- (4) Therefore, either (i) r corresponds to a real object, or (ii) r
  does not correspond to a real object.  (modus ponens on 2, 3)
- (5) Suppose (ii). (Assumption for reductio)
- (6) If (ii), then I can conceive a being y who is greater than x.
  (Premise)
- (7) Therefore, I can conceive of a being y who is greater than x.
  (modus ponens 5, 6)
- (8) But I can't conceive of a being y who is greater than x.
  (Premise)
- (9) Therefore, not-(ii). (5-8, reductio ad absurdum)
- (10) Therefore, (my mental representation of God) r corresponds to a
  real object. (disjunction elimination on 4, 9)
- (11) Therefore, God exists (by 10).

That looks valid to me. Also, the premises look pretty plausible, as interpretations of Anselm. (2) doesn't turn on the specious move Kaye calls (1). (6) looks true because if *x* doesn't exist, then I can imagine a being y > x that is just like x except that it does exist. (That might not be *true*, but it's certainly something Anselm claims!) Finally (8) seems true by definition---assuming conceivability entails possibility, which Anselm does, you shouldn't be able to conceive of something greater than the greatest possible thing.

Comment: What is your point? Do you want to recall Anselm's "proof"? Or do you want to present a better argumentation than Anselm in order to save the ontological claim?

Comment: The point is that Kaye claims the argument is unsound because it relies on (1). I show it doesn't rely on (1). If it is unsound it must be so for different reasons therefore.

Comment: I see. Like you I wonder why Kaye claims that Anselm presupposes (1). I agree with you that Anselm did not presuppose (1).

Comment: Thanks, to make it perfectly clear how my post responds to the op, I take (2) to express all that Anselm means by the Dustin between real and mental existence.

Comment: "Dustin" = Distinction above.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I hope that my edit was correct. Is there a typo in your (1) with the `o` on its own?

Comment: @LePressentiment No, i'm using o as a name for an object in (1).

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry to disturb you about this again, but does your answer clarify why `having an idea of something` differs from `mental existence`? I am confused which one 1 and 2 match.

Comment: Would you please respond in your answer, which is easier to read than comments?

Comment: The unsoundness lies in (3) where you have "the greatest conceivable being". It assumes that it is logically consistent to have such a thing, but this is not at all justified. Consider an analogous "the greatest integer". It is simply logically inconsistent.

Comment: @user21820 I'd think you'd rather want to take issue with (6) than (3). All (3) says is that I have a mental representation of the greatest conceivable being. That looks true to me, even if such a thing is literally inconceivable. I have a mental representation of the largest number and the square circle too, I think, since these are all things about which I can think and about which I can know truths, e.g. that there are no such things. The thing I doubt is (6), which is implicitly relying on the idea that if something is conceivable it is possible. I doubt that principle.

Comment: If you put it that way, then yes. I had trouble following exactly the logical content of your list of points, because it's not formal at all. But based on your explanation in your comment, indeed I agree that conception does not imply possibility, nor does possibility of a greatest possible being imply existence (greatest does not grant necessity in the logical sense).

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question like you.

I do not consider it helpful to approach Anselm's ontological "proof" by making a distinction between *having an idea* and *mental existence*.

The case of this "proof" has been settled by distinguishing

- *being-in-reality* and
- *being-in-the-mind*.

And to note that the latter does not imply the former. This fact had already been noted by a fellow monk of Anselm named Gaunilo.

But distinguishing

- *being-in-the-mind* = *having an idea* and
- *mental existence*

means to mix the levels and to compare things on different levels: *Having an idea* lives on the philosophical level of Anselms argumentation. But *mental existence*, as taken by Kaye, lives on the neurobiological level of firing neurons. Neurobiology is a different level than philosophy.

Possibly in the future neurobiology can explain some mechanism of argumentation, but that's not relevant for the issue of the quote.

**Added**. In my opinion Kaye illustrates her use of the term "mental existence" by the passage

> Consider what happens in your brain when you think of Santa — certain neurons fire.

That's a description on the level of neurobiology. On the opposite, "having an idea" is a description on the level of philosophy of mind. These are two different levels of explanation.

Anyhow I must admit that I consider Kaye's statements a bit cluttered. I do not adhere to her use of the terms.

Comment: Would you please explain further how `having an idea of something` differs from `mental existence`?

Comment: Would you please respond in your answer, which is easier to read than comments?

Comment: @LePressentiment Done.